# How to higlight button color when hover the mouse after a click?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I'm doing a piano application thought to be played on mobile devices (Android). All the piano keys are UI buttons that have the "property" pressed color to a grey one in order to properly indicate when a piano key is emiting sound.
My current problem is that when I first click on a key and after that I drag the mouse over the following keys, only the first one that I clicked is getting the change of color (the idea is that the change of color duration finishes when other key starts sound and then the new key where I pass the mouse-finger gets the grey color).
I also tryied setting the higlighted color property to the same color as the pressed color with the Navigation parameter to none (if it's set to automatic it happens some kind of bug that the color is getting "stuck" until I make sound another key), but the result it's still the same.

**EDIT:**
I update the issue with some progress thath I made:
I'm trying to change the pressed color with a script thanks to the events Pointer enter and exit (both events are placed on a Event trigger in every button).
Code:

```
public class ChangeKeyColor : MonoBehaviour{

    public Button button;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void EnterKey () {
        Debug.Log("Enter the key");
        ColorBlock colors = button.colors;
        colors.normalColor = new Color(179, 179, 179, 255);
        //colors.highlightedColor = new Color32(179, 179, 179, 255);
        button.colors = colors;
    }

    public void ExitKey()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exits the key");
        ColorBlock colors = button.colors;
        colors.normalColor = Color.white;
        //colors.highlightedColor = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
        //colors.pressedColor = Color.white;
        button.colors = colors;
    }

}
```

The only improvement that I obtained is that now when I'm dragging the mouse (maintaning it) the first button returns to white color, but I think that this is happening because now I only setted to gray color the pressed color option...
Does anyone know why the pressed color change that I'm making in the script isn't happening? When I drag the mouse to another key isn't considered as a pressed button?

Regards!

Comment: If you have no problems with detecting which button is pressed during the mouse drag, then I suppose you can add all the buttons to one array (some static property in your script) and deactivate them manually. All, except the pressed one.

Comment: Otherwise, try to use EventTrigger (instead of Button) and OnPointerEnter / OnpointerExit events to figure out which buttons should be pressed.

Comment: Hi @obywan , I'm using the component "Event trigger" with the event "Pointer enter" in order to make the keys sound.  
Can I add to the list the script and execute a function that controls the change of color?

Comment: sure. Just change color manually when you play sound and change it back on OnPointerExit.

Comment: @obywan please see my edited post in order to get the updated issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for the answer, but I finally had some time to try it myself.
What I did is changing color and debug-logging transform's name instead of playing sound.
My code for Images/Buttons (attached to each Image, I didn't use `Button` components):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour {

public Color activeColor, notActiveColor;
private Image thisImage;

void Awake () {
    thisImage = GetComponent<Image>();
}

public void OnPointerClick()
{
    Activate();
}

public void OnPointerEnterAndDown()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        Activate();
    }
}

public void OnPointerExit()
{
    thisImage.color = notActiveColor;
}

private void Activate()
{
    Debug.Log(transform.name);
    thisImage.color = activeColor;
}
}
```

EventTrigger settings:

[image: <code>Event trigger</code> Settings]

And this is what it looks like in the end:

[image]

Comment: Hi @obywan , on first thank you for your reply.  
OnPointerClick will also work on mobile devices? Or that solution is only valid for pc?  
Regards!

Comment: Yes, it works on Android (I've just built this project to test on mobile — it works fine)

Comment: But you should use `PointerEnter`, `PointerExit` and `PointerDown` events in `EventTrigger`. `OnPointerClick` is just a name of the function in my code (a bit confusing naming I must admit)

Comment: Thank you very much @obywan    
Then instead of debug-logging the component name, I should make the sound play on every touch right (by code)? I was actually doing this only when the user pass the mouse over the keys (I think using an venet on the event trigger).

Comment: Yes that's right, you should play sound instead of logging. If this solution works for you, mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi again @obywan
I had to take it out the correct answer bsecause I was testing your example and when I pass the mouse over the button and I exit (activating then the OnPointerExit function), instead of happening the behabior that you ilustrated me, the button disapears letting show the camera background.
I dont know why but it seems that the UI object button desapears...

Comment: @flaurens, take a look at the color and make sure that `Alpha` value is not 0. I bet that is the cause of you current problem — button become transparent.

Answer (score 0):

**(This should be a comment, but it's a little long, so reply me and I'll update the answer)**

I don't know why are you having this problem, I do the simple test creating 2 UI Buttons and setting the highlighted color to red, and the pressed to blue.

By default (there's no script attached to anything) the behaviour is the follow:

1.If I press (and mantain) the click on a button, that button is blue, when I release the "pression", the button keeps red.

2.While this first button is red, if I drag the mouse over the second button, this will be also red.

3.If now I press on the second button, the first behaviour applies to the second button, and the first one will be white again.

This is the following behaviour that you want, according to what I understood. 
So, if this is not the desired behaviour, tell us more about what you want.

Comment: Not exactly, what I want is that pressing your first button (and mantain) change the color to blue (this part is the same you did), but then while I'm maintaining the click I want to drag the mouse to the second button, and then the second color button will change to blue and the first one will change back again to red. What I want is to allow the user to pass the finger all over the screen (in mobile devices) in order to make sound the piano keys and see the secuence change of color

Comment: @flaurens if you want to work in mobile devices, there is no "highlighted" state for the user, as you "don't have cursor".

Comment: Ok, but maybe it's possible to do my idea with the pressed button option? I asume that the first touch in the screen on a piano key is considered as a pressed button right?

Comment: anyway trying to do my idea on pc it's still an issue to me, I don't know how to change the color from the button while I drag the mouse (maintaned pressed from the first button) on the piano...

Comment: @flaurens now I see your problem, this is not the best solution BUT, you can set box colliders on your piano-keys, and control user's input by physics and raycasts, not OnClick events, what do you think?

Comment: Hi @Lotan , I'm not using OnClick events exactly:  
I'm using the component "Event trigger" with the event "Pointer enter" in order to make the keys sound; do you know if its possible to add a script into the Pointerenter list in order to execute a custom function? (the custom function should be the responsible to change the keys colors)